# What metrics should I check if I want to improve performance in mobile application?

Tags: android, ios, metrics, analysis

I'm trying to check and improve my application's performance.

In Web application, we can easily found performance metrics(and guides) like: `LCP` `FCP` `CLS` etc..
And also, these are easy to check when using Lighthouse.

But I cannot found the any metrics of native application(Android, iOS) or analysis tools.
I thought these metrics were in official develop guide, but it wasn't.

The purpose of these metrics is to set a goal and achieve it.

Is there any metrics I can refer to?